# Access - custom "The changes you requested to the table were not succesfull..."

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have set Duplicates(No) to one of my table's ID. Then I created a form with Combobox to select all records from that table and to store selected record in a field of joined table (ID foreign key). If I try to add another record with same ID, Access prompts me with a warning message "The changes you requested to the table were not succesfull...etc).

What I want is to remove this message and create a custom one. Here is what I tried:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Dim sWhere As String
sWhere = "[ID_Table]=" & Me.Combo5
'
If DCount("*", "Table1", sWhere) > 0 Then 

Cancel = True
Me.Undo
MsgBox " Duplicate"
End If

End Sub
```

This code executes If I select whatever value from combobox. Here are my tables:

```
Table1
ID_Table(PK)
Field1
Field2 etc.

JoinTable
ID_Join(PK)
ID_Table1(FK)
ID_Table2(FK)
```

ID Field that has property Duplicates(No) is in Table1 (PK). How can I get this working correctly ?

Comment: How is it not working correctly?

Comment: I have a form, which is continous form of joined table. In form's header I use Dlookup fields to view what Table2 record I wish to "join" with Table1 record. In this continous form I have replaced field ID_Table1(FK) with Combobox that displays records from Table1, and stores It's value into ID_Table1(FK). That creates link. Now If I select whatever value from that Combobox I get this code executed, even if It doesn't exist yet in JoinTable record. So, if It doesn't exist yet, then code should allow me to link tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, what a stupid mistake :

Instead of

```
If DCount("*", "Table1", sWhere) > 0 Then
```

I had to change to

```
 If DCount("*", "JoinTable", sWhere) > 0 Then
```

Code didn't work because I was referencing to wrong Table. Problem solved, thanks for response Matt.